# My timer always returns 0

Tags: haskell, timer

I have created a timer in haskell. The problem is, it always returns 0. I think this is because of laziness, but I do not know how to fix it.

```
import System.CPUTime
timeit::IO ()->IO (Float)
timeit io=do
    start  <-getCPUTime
    action <-seq start io
    end    <-seq action getCPUTime
    return $! (fromIntegral $ end-start)/(10**12)
```

As you can see, I have throw in `seq` and `$!` galor, but to no avail. What do I do?

Here in an example run:

```
*Main> timeit test
What is your name?
Haskell
Your name is Haskell.
0.0
```

Comment: Perhaps a naive question: in what units is the answer provided expressed ?  If in seconds, then `0.0` might be how long (to the nearest 10th of a second) it takes the run-time to execute such a straightforward piece of code.

Comment: getCPUTime returns it in picoseconds.  I divide to get seconds.

Comment: And it requires user input, so it can last as long as 5 seconds.

Comment: And the precision is .01 seconds.

Comment: When I run this on my VM I get `1.0e-2` seconds.

Comment: picoseconds ?!? `1 ps == 10^-12 s` are you sure ?

Comment: Note that `getCPUTime` returns the number of picoseconds of *CPU time* used by the current program, which is different from the *real time* of the program. It is possible that the difference of CPU time used by the program is less than `cpuTimePrecision`, and so is 0.

Comment: Perhaps you should change `seq action getCPUTime` to `deepseq action getCPUTime`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code I got to work

```
import Data.Time.Clock

timeit::IO ()->IO NominalDiffTime
timeit doit=do
    start  <- getCurrentTime
    doit
    end    <- getCurrentTime
    return (diffUTCTime end start)
```

Now for some discussion-

1. From the comments it seemed that you wanted real time, not cpu time, so that is what I wrote.
2. The System.Time libary is deprecated, so I switched you to the Data.Time library.
3. NominalDiffTime holds the time in seconds....
4. NominalDiffTime ignores leap seconds!  In the unlikely event that a leap second is added during the running of the program, a 10 second delay will show up as 11 seconds.  I googled around on how to fix this, and although Data.Time does have a DiffTime type to account for this, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to generate a DiffTime from UTCTime.  I think you may be able to use the Posix time libraries and get seconds from Jan 1, 1970....  Then take the diff, but this seems like to much hastle for a pretty rare bug.  If you are writing software to safely land airplanes however, please dig a bit deeper and fix this problem. :)

Comment: That is what I did except I converted it to float.

Comment: And I am testing my speed for Euler problem 14, which is obviously much more important than airplanes.

Comment: They are not the same, you used `System.CPUTime` and `getCPUTime`

And as a wild guess, you are on windows and this function is broken on this platform

Comment: Could you try something for me?  Copy and paste the code above exactly, then add the following line "main = print =<< (timeit $ threadDelay 10000000)" (you also need to import Control.Concurrent).  This should return 10 plus some small fraction.  If it doesn't, let us know the Haskell version and OS that you are running on.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before and it works well for approximations.  Don't rely on it for very precise times, but it should be accurate to within a millisecond.  I've never tested its accuracy, so use at your own risk

```
import System.CPUTime

timeit :: IO a -> IO (a, Integer)
timeit action = do
    start <- getCPUTime
    value <- action
    end   <- getCPUTime
    return (value, end - start)
```

No explicit strictness required.