# getCPUTime only returns two values (0 or 15625000000) - is this correct?

Tags: windows, haskell, time

It seems that it always return `0` or `15625000000` .

```
import System.CPUTime

main  =  do         
    print =<< getCPUTime
    getLine
    print =<< getCPUTime
    getLine
    return ()
```

Execution

```
>>time.exe
15625000000

15625000000


>>time.exe
0

0


>>time.exe
0

15625000000


>>time.exe
0

0
```

I'm on Windows, I think it's a platform related.

Comment: It means that `GPUTime` in Windows is correct twice a day

Comment: I would suggest adding a sleeper to see what happens but I only found one on hoogle that requires posix, which won't be available on windows.

Comment: Maybe `threadDelay` from `Control.Concurrent`?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [My timer always returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244185/my-timer-always-returns-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getCPUTime` returns the CPU time used by your process. Since your process does practically nothing, it always returns 0 or the next closest thing to it (which in your platform seems to be 15625000000). Note that the time your process is blocked waiting for input doesn't count as CPU time of your process.

Comment: Changing to fib 40 in place of getLine
15625000000
fib : 102334155
25859375000000

So indeed! I was expecting some randomness, but CPU time is deterministic.

Answer (score 4):

From [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=getCPUTime)

`getCPUTime :: IO Integer`

`base System.CPUTime`

Computation `getCPUTime` returns the number of picoseconds CPU time used by the current program. The precision of this result is implementation-dependent.

It could be that windows doesn't have an accurate implementation and returns a 0 instead of the number of picoseconds, note i do not see this behavior on linux or osx.

Comment: Could you run `cpuTimePrecision` on your machine?

I get 1000000000 here, and that's 10^9 picoseconds, that is 10^-3 s, it has to be enough to show input delay.

Comment: I get 10000000000  or 10^10 on both linux and Mac